# Replacing char sequence with char from string in java

Tags: java, html

I want to replace all **llpp** with "**<**" char and all **llqq** with "**>**" from following string in a java code,

```
llpphtmlllqq
llppheadllqqllpptitlellqqCompany Name-Companyllpp/titlellqqllpp/headllqq
llppbodyllqqSome text herellpp/bodyllqq
llpp/htmlllqq
```

I have above string and i want it to be

```
<html>
    <head><title>Company Name-Company</title></head>
    <body>Some text here</body>
</html>
```

please help me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
String targetString = sourceString.replace("llpp", "<").replace("llqq", ">");
```

The `replace` method replaces each instance of the first parameter with the second parameter. Since `String`s are immutable, you have to capture the result of the method by assigning it to a variable.

Note that the above code will effect the replacements you want, though it *won't* format the code the way you've shown. Hopefully that's not something you need, since that would be significantly more complicated.

Answer (score 4):

```
String newString = oldString.replace("llpp", "<").replace("llqq", ">");
```

[`replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) is available from Java 5. before that you had to use `replaceAll` which takes regular expression as first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String#replaceAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: What are the reasons to choose `replaceAll` (using regex) instead of `replace` ?

Answer (score 0):

If in java have a look at String's replace function http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: Besides the fact that there are already answers that even explain `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`, this link-only hint can be placed as comment.